# Combining cubes Issue in Marching Cubes

Tags: unity, marching-cubes

I was trying to implement the marching cubes and combine every little cube this way:

- I get a cube of vertices depending on their surfaceLevel
- I look for the ones that are below the surfaceLevel and get the edges that relates to them
- get a vertice out of the edge using the formula on: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/
- I put every vertex i created based on the edges on mesh.vertices
- I make the order on mesh.triangles based of the edge number on triTable
- i combine everything
  but i get this: [image: problemCombining]

Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/jqetCk8r.
My guess was that the combine order of every marched little cube is not good.
I've got no idea know how to solve this.

ps: the triTable doesn't show in the pastebin, i copied it from the same link above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to convert the raw triangles into welded vertices, face normals and vertex normals. It is a small code, and it works well:

```
void get_vertices_and_normals_from_triangles(vector<triangle> &t, vector<vertex_3> &fn, vector<vertex_3> &v, vector<vertex_3> &vn)
{
    fn.clear();
    v.clear();
    vn.clear();
    
    if(0 == t.size())
        return;

    cout << "Triangles: " << t.size() << endl;
    
    cout << "Welding vertices" << endl;
 
    // Insert unique vertices into set.
    set<vertex_3> vertex_set;
 
    for(vector<triangle>::const_iterator i = t.begin(); i != t.end(); i++)
    {
        vertex_set.insert(i->vertex[0]);
        vertex_set.insert(i->vertex[1]);
        vertex_set.insert(i->vertex[2]);
    }
 
    cout << "Vertices: " << vertex_set.size() << endl;

    cout << "Generating vertex indices" << endl;
 
    // Add indices to the vertices.
    for(set<vertex_3>::const_iterator i = vertex_set.begin(); i != vertex_set.end(); i++)
    {
        size_t index = v.size();
        v.push_back(*i);
        v[index].index = index;
    }
 
    vertex_set.clear();

    // Re-insert modifies vertices into set.
    for(vector<vertex_3>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
        vertex_set.insert(*i);
 
    cout << "Assigning vertex indices to triangles" << endl;
   
    // Find the three vertices for each triangle, by index.
    set<vertex_3>::iterator find_iter;
 
    for(vector<triangle>::iterator i = t.begin(); i != t.end(); i++)
    {
        find_iter = vertex_set.find(i->vertex[0]);
        i->vertex[0].index = find_iter->index;
 
        find_iter = vertex_set.find(i->vertex[1]);
        i->vertex[1].index = find_iter->index;
 
        find_iter = vertex_set.find(i->vertex[2]);
        i->vertex[2].index = find_iter->index;
    }

    vertex_set.clear();

    cout << "Calculating normals" << endl;
    fn.resize(t.size());
    vn.resize(v.size());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < t.size(); i++)
    {
        vertex_3 v0 = t[i].vertex[1] - t[i].vertex[0];
        vertex_3 v1 = t[i].vertex[2] - t[i].vertex[0];
        fn[i] = v0.cross(v1);
        fn[i].normalize();

        vn[t[i].vertex[0].index] = vn[t[i].vertex[0].index] + fn[i];
        vn[t[i].vertex[1].index] = vn[t[i].vertex[1].index] + fn[i];
        vn[t[i].vertex[2].index] = vn[t[i].vertex[2].index] + fn[i];
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vn.size(); i++)
        vn[i].normalize();
}
```

Where the less-than operator is implemented as:

```
inline bool operator<(const vertex_3 &right) const
{
    if(right.x > x)
        return true;
    else if(right.x < x)
        return false;

    if(right.y > y)
        return true;
    else if(right.y < y)
        return false;

    if(right.z > z)
        return true;
    else if(right.z < z)
        return false;

    return false;
}
```

Also, make sure that you sort the vertices before interpolation, if you're using floats instead of doubles. This is because cracks can form in the mesh if the vertices aren't sorted.

```
vertex_3 marching_cubes::vertex_interp(const float isovalue, vertex_3 p1, vertex_3 p2, float valp1, float valp2)
{
    // Sort the vertices so that cracks don't mess up the water-tightness of the mesh.
    // Note: the cracks don't appear if you use doubles instead of floats.
    if (p2 < p1)
    {
        vertex_3 tempv = p2;
        p2 = p1;
        p1 = tempv;

        float tempf = valp2;
        valp2 = valp1;
        valp1 = tempf;
    }

    const float epsilon = 1e-10f;

    if(fabs(isovalue - valp1) < epsilon)
        return(p1);

    if(fabs(isovalue - valp2) < epsilon)
        return(p2);

    if(fabs(valp1 - valp2) < epsilon)
        return(p1);

    float mu = (isovalue - valp1) / (valp2 - valp1);

    return p1 + (p2 - p1)*mu;
}
```

The full codes are at:

https://github.com/sjhalayka/marching_cubes

https://github.com/sjhalayka/opengl1_stlview